# What is the difference between all the CC_CALLBACK_# macros?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm new to cocos2dx and c++.  I have been messing around with the starter HellowWorldScene and noticed this line:

```
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                       "CloseNormal.png",
                                       "CloseSelected.png",
                                       CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));
```

When I change the CC_CALLBACK to CC_CALLBACK_2 xcode complains with "No matching function for call to 'create'".  Why is that?  What does the number at the end of CC_CALLBACK mean?  Also can a function only accept one type of CC_CALLBACK selector?

Comment: At a guess, this is similar to `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in regard to the number of arguments that your callback function expects.

From the docs :

```
#define     CC_CALLBACK_0(__selector__, __target__,...)   std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define     CC_CALLBACK_1(__selector__, __target__,...)   std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define     CC_CALLBACK_2(__selector__, __target__,...)   std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define     CC_CALLBACK_3(__selector__, __target__,...)   std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

As you can see, versions with different numbers expand to different `std::bind` calls.
You can read more about `std::placeholders` here : [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)

Let me know if anything is not clear!

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know why this MenuItemImage::create is having an issue with all the CC_CALLBACK macros except CC_CALLBACK_1

Comment: I'm not sure entirely but, how many arguments does the `menuCloseCallback` take?

Comment: I was just messing around so I added two int arguments to menuCloseCallback and tried using CC_CALLBACK_2 or 3 but it worked fine with CC_CALLBACK_1(HellowWorld::menuCloseCallback, this, 10, 15)

Comment: It's probably outside the scope of the answer, but could you elaborate a bit on the `bind` and `placeholders` in your answer? Seems like it stores arguments for later and replaces them with empty types.